# Destination host unreachable centos 6.5

Tags: centos, networking, ping

I tried config static ip in centos but when I ping in 8.8.8.8 . I get Destination host unreachable . 
Here is ipconfig in pc :
[image]

Here is in ifcfg-eth0
[image]

My network card is NAT mode
Where is my wrong .

Comment: Please post your text *as text* (not screenshots or other images).

Comment: Can you `ping` your gateway (172.16.0.2)?

Comment: If you use NAT show us the IP that your windows computer has on the VMware network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you mixed up your GATEWAY with your IPADDR.

Try pinging your Gateway

`ping 172.16.0.2`

If this works send as the output of this:

```
ip route
```

Is the network adapter of the VM bridged or does it use NAT? It looks like NAT.